# Issues With Arrow Syntax and Binding in React for Grandchild Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, user-interface

I'm trying to create a test page and I'm having trouble with getting some buttons to work.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Icon, Menu, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export class Page extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebarVisible: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Header name='test' onCLick={this.handleIconClick}/>
        )
    }

    handleIconClick = () => {

        console.log('CLICKED');
        let visible = !this.state.sidebarVisible;
        this.setState({sidebarVisible: visible});

    }

}

export class Header extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            iconName: this.props.visible ? 'angle double left' : 'angle double right'
        };
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Menu>
                    <Menu.Item onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                        <Icon name={this.state.iconName}/>
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the above example which I've arrived at from following documentation, looking online for solutions, etc... does not even allow me to click the button ("CLICKED" is never logged).

When I change

```
<Menu.Item onClick={this.props.onClick}>
```

to

```
<Menu.Item onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
```

I get an error stating that:

> this.props.onClick is not a function

I've spent quite some time on this so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to arrow syntax. You have `onCLick` instead of `onClick` when you call `<Header />` component in `<Page />` component.

Change as the following:

```
<Header name='test' onClick={this.handleIconClick} />
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I was scared it was because of something like this! New IDE and theme so it completely got through my syntax checks. Thank you so much.